# Replace repeating special characters in a String - MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

How can I replace n/ repeating characters with a single character?  All special characters `!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]{};:'",<.>/?\|~` I need them to only appear once.  I started embedding "replace"s but that got out of hand and required me to have several replaces per character.

**String Examples:**

- This is great!!!!!!!!!!!
- ''''''look at this!!!!!'''''
- $$$$$$$Money$$$$$$$
- ,,,,,,,,,come on''''''''''''

**Desired Output:**

- This is great!
- 'Look at this!'
- $Money$
- ,come on'

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0.17.

Comment: I'm not sure about the regex syntax in MySQL but generally, you'd be replacing `([!@#$%^&*()_\-+=[\]{};:'",<.>\/?\\|~])+` with `\1` or `$1`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gX7kx/1).

Comment: Did my answer  help you solving your problem? If so, I would be thankful if you could give me upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestions from the guys above I came up with this one:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('''''''look at this!!!!!''''', '([$!&*_;:@#+\'=%^,<.>/?|~])\\1+', '$1');
```

As mentioned beforehand, it captures each occurrence in the first group and replaces with a single character. Tested on v8.0 and seems to work for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following:

```
([&*()_\-+={}[\];:!@#$%^'",<.>\/?\\|~])+$1
```

**PS:** First you should retrieve the desired data with an appropriate query in SQL the standard format of query is as follows:

```
SELECT <col-name> FROM <table>
```

Then you have to update it and send Update query to the database.

For more information see the following links:

- [retrieve query](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html)
- [update query](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

> These question may have more than one solution.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to SQL,  how would I write this into a query? Here is my failed attempt. select 
REPLACE(text,'([&*()_\-+={}[\];:!@#$%^''",<.>\/?\\|~])',+1) as test
from results where text like '%???%'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better and more specific :

```
CREATE FUNCTION `remove_duplicate_chars` (input_text Text, char_to_replace VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS Text
BEGIN
    DECLARE result_text Text;
    DECLARE current_char VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE prev_char VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

    SET result_text = '';

    WHILE i <= LENGTH(input_text) DO
        SET current_char = SUBSTRING(input_text, i, 1);

        IF current_char != prev_char OR current_char != char_to_replace THEN
            SET result_text = CONCAT(result_text, current_char);
        END IF;

        SET prev_char = current_char;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN result_text;
END $$
```

use source like this :

```
SELECT replace_consecutive_chars('aabbcdddaaee', 'd') AS result;
```

result ===>   aabbcdaaee